# Why do I get the exception_with_response 503 Service Unavailable with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception, http-status-code-503

I'm using a bot that used to work perfectly. Since yesterday, I cannot connect with this bot to the website. Manually I can with not any issue. To solve it I tried to use a VPN to change my IP in case the website would block my IP. Maybe it comes from my firewall ?

Configuration :
Windows 10 64bits
Ruby23-x64 (I use to have Ruby24 but downgrade to try to solve the issue)

In the following log it seems to be on RubyGems 2.3.0 but when I do "gem update --system" I have another result so not sure which version it is : 
Bundler 1.16.0 installed
RubyGems 2.7.4 installed

Log :

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:223:in `exception_with_response': 503 Service Unavailable (RestClient::ServiceUnavailable)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:103:in `return!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:809:in `process_result'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:725:in `block in transmit'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:715:in `transmit'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:145:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:52:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient.rb:67:in `get'
        from yobit_bot.rb:57:in `call_api'
        from yobit_bot.rb:85:in `get_market_summary'
        from yobit_bot.rb:171:in `buy_sell_bot'
        from yobit_bot.rb:228:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by replacing the url I try to connect "https://yobit.net/" by "https://www.yobit.net/"